# Animated switcher is not smooth on the first switch

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use animated switcher between two widgets with a duration of 500ms. I noticed that on the first switch the animation is not smooth.
The widget I want to switch to is pretty heavy, so I suspect its build takes longer than the animation duration.
I made two tests-
First, I placed a text widget instead of the widget I wanted to switch to and the animation was smooth again
Second, I changed the duration to 1500ms and noticed that the animation is not perfectly smooth but its smoother.
Because of that, I'm pretty sure that it's because the second widget is heavy and the build takes more than 500ms.
In addition, after the first time I'm switching between them the animation works well and smooth.
So I guess flutter has a building optimization, is that true?
Do you have any workaround or a solution? Maybe build the widget before the animated switcher builds it?

Comment: are you using `debug` [build mode](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes)? if so, try `release` and see what happens

Comment: Ill try it, ive read that after bundeling everything should be faster. But ill be happy if you guys has any other ideas ?

Comment: It would be helpful if yould provide a small snippet of your code, so we can have a look at it. Even a minimal example would help :)

Comment: I dont think a code snippet will help, im animating between two big widget with an animatedSwitcher and a regular setState, there’s not much to see. @Niklas

Comment: So you already tried a `release` build? Optimally on a real device?

Comment: No not yet, because it isnt realy gonna solve my problem, it just gonna maybe make it better, lets say the current widget build takes 600 miliseconds and thats why the animation dosent shows off. And on realse build it will take 300, to thr animation will remain not perfect but just slightly better.

Comment: tried [Flutter performance profiling](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/ui-performance)?

Comment: I got similar issue. Is there any update on this question?